# Can the method of generating functions be applied to linear recursions of order $>4$?

Tags: closed-form, recursion

I just got in touch with the method of solving recursions with generating functions. However, even if it is not mentioned anywhere, it seems to me, this approach is not applicable for recursions of order higher than 4.

**So here comes my question:** Is the method of generating functions applicable to linear recursions of order $k>4$?

Below follows a description of the problem and an explanation, why I think the answer is no, please tell me, if I am right, or have overlooked something.

Generating functions provide a textbook method for solving linear recurrences. If one considers the order-$k$ recurrence problem

$$a_{n+k}=c_0 a_n + c_1 a_{n+1}+...+c_{k-1}a_{n+k-1}$$
with given initial conditions $(a_0,...,a_{k-1})$, one defines the generating function

$$G(z):=\sum_{l=0}^\infty a_l z^l$$ of a complex, formal variable $z$.

For the general problem stated above, one finds that $G$ is of the rational form

$$G(z)=\frac{a_0+a_1z+...+a_{k-1}z^{k-1}}{1-c_0z^k-c_1z^{k-1}-...-c_{k-1}z}$$.

I will not go into details, as this is a standard method, but basically one has to insert the recursion into the above definition of $G(z)$, reformulate all terms via $G(z)$ by index changes and finally solve for $G(z)$.

Now the final step to get the closed form solution is to compute

$$a_n = \partial_z^n G(z)|_{z=0}$$

which is (to my opinion) only possible via franctional decomposition of the rational function $G$. However, this requires to write the denominator in product form, so in general, analytical derivations would be restricted to cases $k\leq 4$.

Comment: Nevertheless you get $a_n=\sum c_i\lambda_i^n$. It is just the case that the $\lambda_i$ cannot necessarily be expressed in terms of the coefficients using radicals.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I wrote an answer that was almost the same. You should make this into an answer.

Comment: Actually in general you need $a_n=\sum p_i(n)\lambda_i^n$ for polynomials $p_i$ of degree one less than the multiplicity of the root $\lambda_i$.  More on topic though, having the roots in term of radicals if often $less$ practical for calculations than saying "$\lambda_i$ is the root of $f(x)$ that's approximately ...". It's pretty easy to find a root of a polynomial near your starting guess to an arbitrary amount of accuracy and that can take less time than approximating a complicated expression in radicals.

Comment: @Nate: I was just coming back to add a comment about polynomials for repeated roots, but I see that you have added it already.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: if you don't want to convert your comment, I will undelete my answer. Answers should not be only in the comments.

Comment: @Nate Sorry, my dictionary makes no difference between radical and root, what exactly do you mean by *having the roots in terms of radicals*?

Comment: @robjohn I would be happy to read it in a more detailed fashion :)

Comment: @flonk: Solvability by radicals means besides addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division, we can take $n^\text{th}$ roots to get the solution. For instance, the quadratic formula involves a square root, and the cubic formula involves a square root and a cube root. Just because a general quintic cannot be solved with radicals, does not mean it does not have roots. Numerically, we can find $5$ complex roots (assuming there are no multiple roots).

Comment: @robjohn Then isn't this just a more elaborate way to say, that for $k>4$ the solution also exists, even though it cannot be brought to a closed form in $n$?

Comment: @robjohn Sorry I still don't get the point. My question was not about the existence of solutions, but the possibility of writing it in a closed form. Thanks for any help...

Comment: @flonk: That depends on what functions you wish to use in your closed form. What is meant when we say that, in general, a fifth degree polynomial cannot solved by radicals, is that we cannot write the solution to every fifth degree polynomial using a composition of $+,-,\times,\div,\sqrt[\large n]{}$ . If those are the only functions you are willing to use, then yes, in general, there is no closed form solution for $n\gt4$. However, if you are willing to use the roots of a general polynomial (extending the notion of $\sqrt[\large n]{}$ ), then we can find a closed form for all $n$.

Comment: @flonk: The [`Root` function in Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Root.html) is used to extend the notion of $\sqrt[\large n]{} $ in answers given by Mathematica.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks, now I got it. It was not clear to me how vague the concept of a *closed form* is.